# Nested Resource Form, Pulling Index Field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models, and one of them is nested. 'Jobs' is inside 'Tanks'. I'm on the form to create a new 'Job' within a 'Tank', and it's not pulling the tank_id into my _form. In the past, I was calling the current_user as a parameter to the form, and that worked fine, but this is totally different since this little project doesn't have users, so to speak. Just a simple tracking system. In the past, the form would already have the form field for model_id filled out, as it was passed to the form. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I'm pretty rudimentary when it comes to this so please be gentle...

tank.tb

```
class Tank < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :jobs
end
```

job.rb

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tank
end
```

jobs_controller.rb

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /jobs
  # GET /jobs.json
  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
  end

  # GET /jobs/1
  # GET /jobs/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /jobs/new
  def new
    @tank = Tank.find(params[:tank_id])
    @job = Job.new
  end

  # GET /jobs/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /jobs
  # POST /jobs.json
  def create
    @job = Job.new(jobs_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save
        format.html { redirect_to tank_jobs_path(:tank_id, @job), notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /jobs/1
  # PATCH/PUT /jobs/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.update(job_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @job }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /jobs/1
  # DELETE /jobs/1.json
  def destroy
    @job.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tank_jobs_path(:tank_id) }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_job
      @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def job_params
      params.require(:job).permit(:tank_id, :jobnum)
    end
end
```

app/views/jobs/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for ([@tank, @job]) do |f| %>
  <% if @job.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@job.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this job from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @job.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tank_id %><br>
    <%= f.number_field :tank_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :jobnum %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :jobnum %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

EDIT - Including my tank_show view:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Gastype:</strong>
  <%= @tank.gastype %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Level:</strong>
  <%= @tank.level %>
</p>

<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_tank_path(@tank) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', tanks_path %> |
<%= link_to 'New Job Assignment', new_tank_job_path(@tank,@job) %>
```

Comment: You are using same form for `new` and `edit` actions?

Comment: Can you post your params?

Comment: Well, when I try to bring up /tanks/1/jobs/1/edit, it errors out and complains about "undefined method job_path".

<%= form_for ([@tank, @job]) do |f| %>

{"tank_id"=>"tank_id",
 "id"=>"1"}

And when I'm on the error page, the URL in the page is: http://localhost:3000/tanks/tank_id/jobs/1/edit